# SQL Server 2014 - Disabled All Admin Users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions

I made the most ridiculous thing. I accidentally disabled both remote logins and database accesses for the Administrator accounts (including the one with Windows Authentication (Administrator account) and sa account on the production server! Please tell me a way that there is a way to access the server with administrator privileges! :(

Is it possible from an installation or some kind of command line etc?

Again, Administrator account IS disabled for SQL Server (but I have remote connection to server, the account itself is working...) So I literally cannot access to the sql instance with admin privileges.

Comment: Single user mode should help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

Comment: Check out answer for alternative to single user mode if you're still having a hard time with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get back in.  :)

1. Go into SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Select SQL Server Services
3. On the right side of the pane, find your instance and right-click for Properties
4. On the Startup Parameters tab, in the Specify a startup parameter box, type -m and then click Add. (That's a dash then lower case letter m.)
5. Click OK and restart.
6. [MSDN suggests launching Management Studio as an administrator for 2014.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)  The traditional way is to use SQLCMD -E.  Either way.

(If it doesn't let you because that account is explicitly denied, close the window, run the command line as a different user, and try again.)

Once you're connected, you should be able to create a new login

```
CREATE LOGIN [YOURDOMAIN\SomeUser] FROM WINDOWS;
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [YOURDOMAIN\SomeUser];
```

or

```
CREATE LOGIN TempLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'SomeReallyGoodPassword';
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER TempLogin;
```

and/or enable the disabled accounts.

```
ALTER LOGIN yourLogin ENABLE  
ALTER LOGIN AnotherLogin ENABLE
```

Because this is production and this requires a restart, you'll have to do it after hours.  Good luck!

Comment: Heyya.. I don't know what I am doing wrong but this is so not working! I can confirm that SQL is now in single user mode (sql server agents are disabled) but when I try either SQLCMD -E or connecting from the SSMS, it still tells me that "INTPRODV01\Administrator" account is "disabled". I am seriously stuck and in trouble lol. And I know this is production but I already messed some stuff up, need to resolve this fast :D

Comment: Shift-right-click command  or SSMS and choose "run as," then try a user that shouldn't be disabled.  It should let that user in.  (You may have to temporarily elevate that user.)

Comment: Okay I managed that. But now it says its in single mode and only one administrator can connect here. But I have no connections anywhere from there? Is there something I am missing? Plus the other user is actually an administrator, it is a separate account...

Comment: I am literally lost... I have stopped every sql service out there but it still says another administrator is connected. How is that even possible? Please I am desperate :(

Comment: Did you close your other attempt to connect?

Comment: Yes, literally everything is closed and all services are down... I am so confused...